# Ограничить количество выполнений цикла

Tags: node.js

Есть цикл вида

```
filter.mat.some(fw => {
      if (message.content.includes(fw)) {
      // Код
      }
}
```

Если в message.content находятся два слова из строки fw, цикл срабатывает несколько раз. Мне необходимо ограничить количество выполнений цикла, а именно, до 1. Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

```
filter.mat.some(fw => {
  if (message.content.includes(fw)) {
    // Код
    return true; // !!!
  }
}
```